# Sonar requests to rename Jetpack Compose functions

Tags: kotlin, sonarqube, android-jetpack-compose

Sonar displays **Rename function to match the regular expression ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$** for any composable Jetpack Compose function starting with an uppercase. Is it possible to somehow suppress those logs?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the platform for Compose apps for now, since clearly, the developers have not yet adapted to the framework. Compose encourages you to use function names starting with an uppercase letters, but they are still 'functions', which traditionally start with a lowercase letter and hence the warning.

Unless they provide a way to manipulate the logs explicitly (check their FAQs), there's not much you can do, other than temporarily stopping their product's use in files containing `@Composable` definitions.

Comment: That's exactly what we want to do, because layout in inherently complex and we keep getting cognitive complexity warnings, that make it more complex to satisfy the warning. So, is there any way to tell SQ to ignore a function with a @Composable annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is the best solution but at this moment I have not found better.
Just simply disable the inspection (alt+enter) at the warning and you should see the option.

I am looking forward for better idea.

Answer (score -1):

In your Sonarqube Quality Profiles, change the kotlin:S100 rule ("Method names should comply with a naming convention") from

```
^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

to the "Sonar way":

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```